# how to cURL SSL URL with http authentication in php?

Tags: php, html, authentication, ssl, curl

I need to load protected Image from remote URL (VM screen shot by Esxi).

I used this code in php:

```
<?php
  $c = curl_init($url);
  $authString = 'User:Pass';
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $authString);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)

  $content = curl_exec($c);
  $contentType = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
  header('Content-Type:'.$contentType);
  print $content;
?>
```

But it does not work and nothing loads (even there is no error).

**what's the problem?**

Is there a better method to directly show images behind authentication?

I just want to show the image in html.

Thanks.

-------------------- Sample Access

Url: https://fr-109.vcenter.top/screen?id=23

Username: uname | Password: A@pass#2020

Output will be like this:
[image: Sample Output after authentication]

Comment: HTTP authentication is no different with HTTP vs. HTTPS. If nothing loads it might for example be that the target is not reachable by HTTPS (firewall?) or maybe something else (nothing to reproduce so unable to tell) - but it is not related to how the HTTP authentication is done.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich, if I use web browser to open the url after submitting user and password image will show.  Are you confirm my above code? so I can look for other options.

Comment: Does your browser run on the same system as your PHP code? Do both use the system proxy (or both use no proxy)?

Comment: yes, same machin and same network setting. this is sample url:
https://fr-109.vcenter.top/screen?id=15

Comment: If I try this URL I get a security warning since the CA is not trusted, but you seem to ignore such problems in your curl code. If I try to use curl on the command line with this URL I get immediately a response code 401 (authentication required) if I give no credentials but get no response for a few seconds if the credentials are wrong. This seems to be some brute-force protection of the server, maybe you've run into this too. I cannot test with valid credentials since I don't have any.

Comment: You're right, I added a sample access to my question.

Comment: What does `curl_error` say?

Comment: @M.Abooali: The username and password do not work even within the browser.  In the browser I get with this an authentication error after the anti-brute-force delay of a few seconds. The same I get with your PHP code (after fixing on `$ch` into `$c` and adding a missing semicolon). So at least for invalid credentials the behavior is the same.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich , That's it ! I forgotten to change all `$ch` to `$c` on last update. The problem solved after correcting the code.